# D365 simplified connection Azure App Services

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, office365, azure-web-app-service, dynamics-crm-online

I'm using the simplified connection to D365 from the *Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.dll* Example can be found in the SDK *SDK\SampleCode\CS\QuickStart\SimplifiedConnection.cs*

The issue is that it doesn't work when the site is deployed to an Azure App Service (former web sites) while it works fine running the site locally.

The exception is very general:

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

Any of you have seen this or knows the issue/resolution?

```csh
CrmServiceClient crmConn = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM"].ConnectionString);
IOrganizationService crmService = crmConn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

```xml
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CRM" connectionString="AuthType=Office365;Url=https://instance.crm4.dynamics.com; Username=name.name@domain.onmicrosoft.com; Password=Lu555" />
```

**EDIT WHEN RESOLVED**
Added following listener in web.config [Source](https://blog.vertica.dk/2016/03/04/crm-2016-unable-to-login-to-dynamics-crm/)

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />
 <sources>
 <source name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient"
 switchName="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient"
 switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
 <listeners>
 <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" />
 <remove name="Default" />
 <add name ="fileListener" />
 </listeners>
 </source>
<source name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl"
 switchName="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl"
 switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
 <listeners>
 <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" />
 <remove name="Default" />
 <add name ="fileListener" />
 </listeners>
 </source>
 </sources>
 <switches>
  <add name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient" value="Verbose" />
 <add name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl" value="Verbose" />
 <add name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.WebResourceUtility" value="Verbose" />
 </switches>
 <sharedListeners>
 <add name="fileListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="XRMToolingLogs.log" />
 </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: FYI, `CrmServiceClient` implements `IOrganizationService` so you can use it directly in most cases, unless you specifically need OrganizationServiceProxy for some reason.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question?

Comment: Maybe you use your own ADFS for authentication, which is not available through the Internet? In such case this would work locally (because ADFS is in your internal network), but your App Service will not be able to log in (because it cannot access ADFS server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the listener above, I got following error

> *Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference*

what makes me think there is an issue with NuGet packages, as I have installed all through Manage NuGet Packages in Visual Studio.

I've resolved the error by adding this in the web.config. After this, my web site connected fine to D365 in an Azure web site.

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is an issue with the connection. Not sure, it may be an issue with reading the connection string - double-check you have the exact same string in the local web.config as you have entered in the Connection String configuration UI for the your Azure App Service.

Try modifying your code to throw an exception id the connection is not ready, so that you can get the underlying CRM error:

```
CrmServiceClient crmConn = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM"].ConnectionString);
if (!crmConn.IsReady)
{
    throw new Exception($"Crm Connection Not Ready. Last error: {crmConn.LastCrmError}");
}
IOrganizationService crmService = crmConn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

Comment: Thanks, with this code I got error: Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM, which made me found the web of the listener above, from which I got actual error.